# How to reference css in actionlink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

A actionlink like:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("more", "myControl", new { id = item.ID },
     new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "pop", OnComplete = "showdetail" },
     new { @class = "search" })
```

Then I set css in css file like:

```
a.search 
{...}
a:search.hover 
{...}
```

It doesn't work. If I change css name is css file as:

```
.search 
{...}
```

It seems work only in Firefox, not work in IE.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS appears to be incorrect; you will want to define it as:

```
a.search { ... }
a.search:hover { ... }
```

Comment: No; you have a typo in your original CSS. The hover selector should read `a.search:hover` not `a:search.hover`.

Comment: Thanks. Keep new { @class = "search" } and change css as a.search { ... } a.search:hover { ... } , then It works for Firefox, But not work for IE. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of IE? If it's IE6 you may need to go with an alternate solution. Does `a:hover { ... }` work for you? Does `.search:hover { ... }`? http://www.google.com/search?q=css+hover+ie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a has more approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I use IE7. I tried to remove a.search:hover { ... } in css file and tried it again. Still not work for IE. I use this css to display a image for the action link.

Comment: Find out the reason: In order to use image for this link, I change the actionlink call as: <%= Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "myControl",...), Firefox seems recognize the space, but IE removes all of them and display nothing. What's the solution?